# Jenkins: SonarQube analysis could not be completed because the analysis configuration file could not be found

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

We just installed a Jenkins and a SonarQube server.

I already created the SonarQube project, and now I'm configuring the SonarQube part on jenkins.

I've a weird behavior:
Sometimes, jenkins(or the sonarqube runner, I don't know) is creating a whole bunch of configuration files for sonarqube in the `.sonarqube` folder of my workspace. In this case, it seems to work, the results are published. But sometimes(without any changes in between), thoses files are missing, and then the build fails with the following message:

```
11:39:55.091  SonarQube analysis could not be completed because the analysis configuration file could not be found:
D:\Jenkins\workspace\MyProjectName\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml.
```

My sonarQube and jenkins are both being executed on a Windows server 2012 computer(the same in fact). I've an authentication token filled in the sonarqube configuration, and I've the "Enable injection of SonarQube server configuration as build environment variables" checked.

I'm not sure to fully understand the process:

1. Should I create myself this project, or is it something that Jenkins should create automatically? If I should create it manually, how and where?
2. If this is something that should be created automatically, why is it not working?

Comment: This sounds like a file permissions issue or perhaps a file locking problem. Try cleaning out the workspace between runs and see if this persists.

Comment: But why if I trigger a new build after that it works?

Comment: Because the resource has finally been released by GC?

Comment: I also get similar error, I have two project, for ProjectA I never get this message. For projectB I always get this message. Did you get the fix?

Comment: @J4N did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @fuzzi nope :( I deleted all the output directory manually, it helped, but sometimes I still got the issue(but we updated jenkins recently and I didn't got this in the last month, maybe it helped?)

Answer (score 1):

Although Jenkin's context is specific (and the question is old), the answer is more general (and still valid). You can find it on this topic: [SonarQube analysis could not be completed because the analysis configuration file could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55268635/3734141).

**TLDR;** Look at the beginning of the SonarQube session, then you find the REAL problem. The last message is only a kind of not-so-useful summary.

Comment: Thanks I found the actual error at the top of the log.